# Multiple Ruby & gems on MacOS Catalina. How to uninstall and the best option to install a clean ruby/gem/bundler on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I have been trying to follow different tutorials on how to install ruby, gem, bundler, and [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to compile my website after re-installing MacOS. None of the tutorials worked and I'm apparently left with multiple installations of Ruby and gem that none of them work. For example, jekyll is run on one installation and bundler is run on another. Therefore, nothing works.

When I search for gem, I find it in the following locations:

```
$ find / -name gem  2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/gem
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.1_2/bin/gem
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/gem
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.7.1_2/bin/gem
/System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/gem
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/ali/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/gem
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/ali/.rbenv/shims/gem
/Users/ali/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/gem
/Users/ali/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

Could you explain how should I uninstall and purge each of them and have a clean installation of gem that works on MacOS and does not conflict with the internal Ruby (which I'm advised neither to remove nor to use it)

Comment: Sounds like you just need to set up the [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) version manager that you already have installed.

Comment: The problem is that the crucial commands (gem,ruby,Jekyll,bundle) are assigned to different installations and hence nothing works. What's the proper way to delete each installation?

Comment: `rbenv` can manage different Ruby versions and their associated gems (that is what it does), so you would just need to select the desired Ruby, then install/remove the gems for that version as desired.  The [rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions) has instructions.

Comment: @red_menance Does rbenv has some sort of isolation like virtualenv in Python? If so, how do you activate/deactivate and rbenv environment so that it is not affected by the other installations and the /usr/bin defaults set by the others?

Comment: It isn't a virtual environment, it intercepts Ruby commands (using shim executables injected into your PATH) to determine which Ruby installation to pass the command to.  Again, all the details are in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use either rbenv or rvm, both are ruby version manager

Comment: The problem is that the crucial commands (gem,ruby,Jekyll,bundle) are assigned to different installations and hence nothing works. What's the proper way to delete each installation?

Comment: the default ruby command is still pointing to the system installed one. I am not sure which version of ruby is used when I run rails. Bundle install new gems at times ask for sudo password.